# What is this thing that holds in a storm window called?

Tags: windows

I would like to replace these things that hold in storm windows on a 80 year old house but I do not know what they are called, so I am having difficulty looking them up to buy more.  What is the piece that toggles called?

It turns rotates and when it is horizontal it holds a storm window in place.  When it is vertical the storm window can be removed.

[image: Trying to figure out what this piece is called]

Comment: I remember the term butterfly latch...

Answer (score 1):

Double wing window screen clip ???

https://www.lowes.com/pl/Window-screen-clips-Window-screen-hardware-Window-hardware-Hardware/4294711068

Answer (score 1):

So I googled "butterfly latch" and then a related result was "turn button latch" and I think that is the answer.  Window screen clip is the name of the smaller clips that are designed to hold a modern style screen in over a window.

Comment: I have some.They are still out there,